# Как можно в гнуплот нарисовать линию тренда сгладить график?

Tags: gnuplot

Есть у меня файл с точками графика. Точки дискретные, хочу сгладить их. Кокой командой это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Сделать это можно командой `smooth`. Вот например, есть у Вас набор точек, пусть это массив, но это не важно, в котором протабулирована какая-то функция (это код для gnuplot 5.2):

```
array A[25]
do for [i=1:25] { A[i] = sin(i * 3*pi/25.0) }
```

Если этот массив нарисовать просто командой

```
plot A title "sin(x)" with lines
```

то получится ломаная кривая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же мы к выводу добавим еще команду `smooth` с соответствующим параметром, то получится сглаженная:

```
plot A title "sin(x)" with lines smooth bezier
```

[image: сглаженная кривая]

У gnuplot есть несколько вариантов сглаживания, о них можно почитать в документации, например так: `help smooth`. Соответственно, нужно использовать тот способ, который больше подходит для решаемой задачи. Возможно, Вам больше подойдет `smooth csplines`. Кроме этого, на результат сглаживания влияет такой параметр как `samples`. По умолчанию он равен 100. Если результат сглаживания не удовлетворяет (остаются углы на кривой), попробуйте сделать этот параметр больше, например `set samples 1000`.

Comment: Спасибо очень помогло.